# Switch the Odd Ones Out #6 (Easy)

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image: OOO6]

The 6th in the series. What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) are the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*created by myself*

Comment: is the organisation of the two sets significant? or is the order random?

Comment: @Jasen The sets are independent of each other but the patterns they are based on are very similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting to identify patterns:

> [image]

Observing

> there are a handful of patterns one line/change away from others. Not sure if that is relevant yet.

First guess

> is to swap top right of a-i (c) and mid right of 1-9 (6).

Comment: Your "guessing" was perfect! ;) That switch also make sure the distribution of filled and hollow circles is even out among the lines and columns, and some more minor details add up to the best patterns available.

Comment: @Plarsen What other details? Didn't even think about it being a distribution of the items across rows or columns.

Comment: @JordanJD Every small figure follow a pattern, for example in the right pattern, center figure: Alternating triangle with plus/dot from left to right and top to bottom (the triangles are somewhat distorted with an overlay of dot/lines and pluses following other patterns). The center figure in the left figure is also alternating triangle with plus/dot.